# How to get data from a URL and convert it into json?

Tags: java, json

I am trying to get data from a URL and store it in json format using the code below:

```
String fullURL="http://XXX:8101/Myapp/XXX/XXX";

        URL u = new URL(fullURL);
            System.out.println(fullURL);
            HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            System.out.println("Message :"+huc.getResponseMessage());
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(huc.getInputStream()));

            JSONArray a = (JSONArray) parser.parse(rd);

            for (Object o : a)
            {
                org.json.simple.JSONObject device = (org.json.simple.JSONObject) o;



                double kw = (double) device.get("value");
                System.out.println(kw);
                //getKw().setKw(kw);

                String sensortype = (String) device.get("senorType ");
                System.out.println(sensortype);
                //getSensorType().setSenorType(sensortype);

                Timestamp dateTime = (Timestamp) device.get("serverTimeStamp");
                System.out.println(dateTime);
                //getServerTimeStamp().setServerTimeStamp(dateTime);

  }
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray.
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix this?

i changed based on user comment finally my array is:

```
[
  {

    "value": 777,
    "percentage": 0,
    "serverTimeStamp": 1436900289000,
    "sensorType": "S"

  },
  {
    "value": 777,
    "percentage": 0,
    "serverTimeStamp": 1436900289000,
    "sensorType": "V"
  },
  {
    "value": 777,
    "percentage": 0,
    "serverTimeStamp": 1436900289000,
    "sensorType": "R"
  }
]
```

How come I am getting a **java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double** exception?

Comment: can you attach json string with your question?

Comment: From exception it look like response is JSON object like {"name": "xyz"} not JSON array like [{"name": "xyz"} ]  . Please print the content and post it here.

Comment: ya you are right @RishiSaraf. i changed my code please look into that now.

Comment: please look my code now @Dev

Comment: why are you not directly passing huc.getResponseMessage() to parser like  parser.parse(huc.getResponseMessage()) I think through Bufferreader parser is not reading complete stream and that's you are facing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking At your code, you are trying to cast value in `double` which is `wrong` ,you will get `long` instate of `double` when trying to get value of key `"value"` from `JSONObject`.To get your desire result first cast to `long` and then in `double`.

```
double kw = (double)((long) device.get("value"));
```

Other thing  what I have observed is you are trying to cast value of key `"serverTimeStamp"`  to `Timestamp`  which is `wrong` ,instate you will get `long`  the you have to create new Instance of Timestamp .

```
Timestamp dateTime = new Timestamp ((long) device.get("serverTimeStamp"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`device.get("value")` is returning a `Long` value which cannot be case to `Double`.

So change it to this:

`long kw = (long) device.get("value");`

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it like this.

```
 ((Number) device.get("value")).doubleValue();
```

You will never get Class cast exception if the returned instace is a number like int, long, float, double etc.